# RxJS Observable Recursive Permutation with Expand

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have the string `CAKES`.

I would like every permutation of it (i.e., `SKACE`, `SEKAC,`  etc). I've tried doing it with `Rx.Observable.prototype.expand` but I can't seem to get expand to do a standard permutation algorithm.

How would this be done somewhat as follows?

```
import Rx from rxjs;

Rx.observable.of('CAKES')
  .expand(...)
  .subscribe(p=>console.log(p))

/* logs every permutation of CAKES = "SKACE", "SEKAC", etc. ... */
```

Reason: Purely academic purposes. I think that expand can't be used this way and would like to see if someone can establish that it can. Maybe someone who reads this will have a real use case.

Comment: `SKANE`? From `CAKES`? Where's the `N` from and where did the `C` go?

Comment: What does the string permutation and rx have in common? What is the use case? Why not simply use generator function? Why not creating observable from any implementation of the algorithm? And why would you expect rx to handle the string permutation for you?